# Load data infile default value not inserting in table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm importing a csv file using LOAD DATAINFILE

The csv columns are NAME,TYPE,STATUS

my table structure is

```
Name  : varchar
TYPE  : Varchar
Status: Tiny int default value 1
```

I use this stmt :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/names.csv' 
INTO TABLE users FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

When I use the above statement it has to insert the status value as 1 for each row, but it is not inserting the same.
Please advise.

Comment: Are your "lines" really terminated with space characters?

Comment: Post example CSV data. I find it doubtful that you have `' '` line terminators instead of `'\n'`

Comment: What does the CSV actually contain in the `STATUS` column for records that are being incorrectly inserted?

Comment: CSV does not contain status column ,but default i want to give status as 1 during insertion.

Comment: You can do an update action to set `Status` column the same value in table after loading all data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When loading a file, MySQL expects that it has the same number of columns as the destination table, unless you specify otherwise, even if the missing column has a default value. So supply a column list to your `LOAD` statement, and a literal 1 for the value of `STATUS`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/names.csv' 
INTO TABLE users 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  ENCLOSED BY '"' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
  IGNORE 1 LINES 
  (`name`, `type`, 1)
```

You can also do it with a `SET` clause:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/names.csv' 
INTO TABLE users 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  ENCLOSED BY '"' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
  IGNORE 1 LINES 
  (`name`, `type`)
  SET `status` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

After you execute the query , check for any warnings using

```
show warnings
```

Default value is 0 for numeric data types and '' for strings.

So you should have set default value 1 while creating the table

```
create table tableName
(
name nvarchar(100) not null,
type nvarchar(100) not null,
status smallint default 1
);
```