# Uploading Excel sheet data into SQL database via a website

Tags: php, excel

I am using `php` to develop my website and I need to be able to browse for and upload an `Excel` sheet. I then need to store the information in an `SQL` database.

I realise this is an relatively open question but I am have looked for information on how to do this and have not got very far. Storing the data in the SQL database is fine but I am not sure how to upload the spreadsheet such that it can be read by the website.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: So out of the dozens of PHP libraries (such as [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)) for reading Excel files, or the option to convert it to a CSV and use MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` option - which have you decided to use? And what's your question about it?

Comment: Excellent - thanks. Will look through this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question contains a lot of topics, I'll try a short summary on what has to be taken care of in order to solve your issue at hand.

**(1) File Upload**

First you have to make an upload available. Basically you have at least two components.

1. The HTML form
2. some (php) code to work with the file.

Example HTML code:

```
<form action="your_upload_script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Your XLS file: <input type="file" name="xlsfile" size="50" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

A simple, but solid example php code can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131023013050/https://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php).

Keep in mind, uploading files can have a few more issues, p.e. regulated upload sizes and such.

**(2) Parsing the Excel file**

Now that your file is uploaded, you have to parse it. I recommend using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), which is a ...

> ... Project providing a set of classes for the PHP programming
> language, which allow you to write to and read from different
> spreadsheet file formats, like Excel (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007
> (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx, CSV, Libre/OpenOffice Calc .ods, Gnumeric, PDF,
> HTML, ...

**(3) Storing the values in your tables**

While or after parsing the spreadsheets you'll eventually have to store it in your tables. Whatever you do, please refrain from using the old mysql connector in php, since this one is old and deprecated. Use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Again, this is only the short story. You'll eventually encounter more challenges and issues on the way.

Answer (score 2):

You could export your file as CSV, upload it and parse it with `fgetcsv()`. From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

```
$row = 1;
if (($fh = fopen("excel.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            //make query and insert into database
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the uploaded excel file using PHPExcel

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Download Link : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 1):

First, your Excel file has to be in CSV format, otherwise it will be a lot more difficult to insert data in your database (you have to parse it with PhpExcel for example).

If your Excel file is CSV, then you have to use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html).

You can see an example here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10897669/1788704