# how to upload excel files using php?

Tags: php

I want to upload excel files  and store that data to my db. Sometimes it contain large data because it is leave management or kpi files.
I want to export my excel file and get all data along with sub tables(pivot tables) from that file. And the files are contain different data.
Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: You can use phpExcel to parse xls files

Comment: The data and format of excel will different , so if it possible to upload that type of files.

Comment: I had same problem, I solve it by installed xls2csv programm. (for example it's `catdoc` package on ubuntu) run external process for convers xls to csv and parse csv data.

Comment: What is the problem you're stuck on exactly?

Comment: I want to export my excel file and get all data along with sub tables(pivot tables) from that file. And the files are contain different data.

Comment: And the *problem* in doing that is...?

Comment: i am upload excel using php libraries, but its fixed on same format data. when the order of pivot table is different its cannot working create php error.

Answer (score 4):

First, your Excel file has to be in CSV format, otherwise it will be a lot more difficult to insert data in your database (you have to parse it with PhpExcel for example).

If your Excel file is CSV, then you have to use LOAD DATA INFILE.

You can see an example here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10897669/1788704

And you can have a look on below code if it helps you

```
$row = 1;
if (($fh = fopen("excel.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            //make query and insert into database
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Excel file upload is normal things. I want to export my excel file and get all data along with sub tables(pivot tables) from that file. And the files are contain different data.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload Excel files just like you upload normal files in PHP. Nothing special about Excel. However, if you want to parse the data in excel, as k102 pointed out phpExcel is a nice option.

If your question was about PHP file uploads then, refer [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)